# Passing variable argument to .ps1 script not working from Github Actions

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, arguments, github-actions

I need to pass branch name as a parameter to .ps1 script using Github Actions. 
                Github Actions part:

```
    runs-on: windows-latest
    env:
      DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: 'true'

    steps:
    - name: Extract branch name
      shell: bash
      run: echo "${GITHUB_REF}"
      id: extract_branch

    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Run a one-line script
      run: .\Scripts\my_script.ps1 -branch_name ${GITHUB_REF}
      shell: powershell
```

.ps1 part:

```
##############################################
#Script Title: Download File PowerShell Tool
#Script File Name: Download-File.ps1 
#Author: Ron Ratzlaff  
#Date Created: 4/21/2016 
##############################################

#Requires -Version 3.0
param($branch_name)


"Current branch"
$branch = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
"$branch"
"${branch}"
"${GITHUB_REF}"
"$GITHUB_REF"
"$branch_name"
"{branch_name}"
Write-Host $branch_name
```

.ps1 part is shown by me in order to display branch name inside of the .ps1 script using different ways of displaying. Because of branch name depends a lot of scripts logic.
So, it does not display anything. 
But:

1. `run: echo "${GITHUB_REF}"` in `Extract branch name` part fully displays the branch name
2. If I pass hardcoded argument like this `run: .\Scripts\my_script.ps1 -branch_name customtext` it will be passed to the script and successfully displayed in different ways.

How to achieve passing value of `GITHUB_REF` and read/display it inside .ps1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Accessing environment variables in Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7) is different from bash, you need to prefix it with `env:`. For your script, you can access the ref using `$env:GITHUB_REF`.

Alternatively, you can use the templating that GitHub Actions expose by replacing the `run` property with `.\Scripts\my_script.ps1 -branch_name ${{github.ref}}` to populate `branch_name` parameter.